# Mistake done in this P&C of seating people.

Tags: permutations, combinations

Q. Let 12 seats be occupied by 4 people such that there must be at least two empty seats between any two person. Number of possible arrangement is

My approach: Arrange four people now put two-two empty seats between them like

```
A--B--C--D
```

This makes `4!`

Now add left two places by `5*5` but that makes wrong answer. Final answer by me is `4! * 5 *5`

What is my mistake and how to correct it **by this method**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you say, let us first pick the order that the people are sitting ignoring the condition that there must be any empty seats in-between them at all and then place two empty seats in the middle of each.  This step has $4!$ number of ways it can occur and our current setting looks like:  $A\underline{~}\underline{~}B\underline{~}\underline{~}C\underline{~}\underline{~}D$ for some arrangement of $A,B,C,D$.

This only accounts for ten of the twelve seats however.

Additional empty seats may be placed to the left of the first person, between the first two, between the second two, between the third two, or after the fourth person in the following locations (possibly multiple seats in the same location):

$\square A\square\underline{~}\underline{~}B\square\underline{~}\underline{~}C\square\underline{~}\underline{~}D\square$

Let $x_1$ denote the number of the final empty seats that you place in the first square.  Let $x_2$ denote the number of the final empty seats that you place in the second square, etc...

We have then the following system:

$\begin{cases}x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4+x_5=2\\
0\leq x_1\\
0\leq x_2\\
\vdots\\
0\leq x_5\end{cases}$

From earlier examples using the stars-and-bars approach, we know that the number of solutions to this equation is given by $\binom{5+2-1}{5-1}=\binom{6}{4}=15$

We have then as a final answer, the total number of arrangements is $4!\cdot 15$

---

Your mistake in saying the final step can be accomplished in $5\cdot 5$ number of ways is that you double count some scenarios.  Say you picked to the left of $A$ as the first part and to the left of $B$ as the second part.  This is also counted in the scenario that you picked to the left of $B$ for the first and to the left of $A$ for the second.  Not every situation is double counted however, for example to the left of $A$ twice.

Specifically, each time you picked two different options, you double counted.  Taking this into consideration, by subtracting the number of ways of picking two different options, we arrive at the correct answer for the number of ways of completing the second step.  $5\cdot 5 - \binom{5}{2}=25-10=15=\binom{6}{2}$

Comment: Ooh great. Thanks.